# Redux saga pass parameter like true or false flag in api response after use this flag in component

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Yield put ({‘API RESPONSE’, payload:users.data,flag :true})

I have pass key like above how to use that flag key in component

Ex :- If flag true response success
Then show some alert in component

Comment: https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.